# Failing to create new migration

Tags: laravel-5

I want to create a new table, users_profile 
here is the migration code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersProfileTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('country');
             $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('users_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');               
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users_profile');
    }
}
```

facing an error

> base table or view already exists: 1050 Table "users" already exists

here is the migration code of users

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void

     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Although i am creating a new migration, a new table only i am declaring a primary key of users table as foreign key in users_profiles but facing the above error
help please!

Comment: Just a word of advice, Use Laravel Nomenclature to avoid these kind of issues. Always define your table names as plural snakecase and use singular camelcase model to access them.

Comment: Let me know if your problem has been reolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of advice, Use Laravel Nomenclature to avoid these kind of issues. Always define your table names as plural snakecase and use singular camelcase model to access them.

In your case, change your table name to: `user_profiles` and use `UserProfile` model to access it automatically.

Ofocurse you need to change your class name in your migration accordingly: **CreateUserProfilesTable**

I believe it should resolve your issue.

I believe you are using : `php artisan migrate` and as users table already exists , running migration for users table again gives that error.

Use: `composer dump-autoload` and then `php artisan migrate:refresh`
to rollback all of your migrations and reinstall migrations.

Comment: Are you trying `php artisan migrate` after creating this new migration? If yes then use: `php artisan migrate:refresh` instead

Comment: i have used php artisan migrate:refresh even then same issue

Comment: Run :
`php artisan config:clear` then 
`composer dump-autoload` then 
`php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to your database and drop Schema table ("users") and also remove entry in Schema table ("migrations") and run your migrations again...your problem is solve....